# Why you can't render from 2 JSX element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

My goal is to render `<Route />` with `array.map` method. Right now, I am trying to pass the return value using react hook, but the problem is `localhost:3000/login` return `<div>Login</div>` while `localhost:3000/dashboard` return nothing.

My expected result is when I visit `localhost:3000/dashboard` the JSX.element return `<div>Dashboard</div>`

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const PublicRouteComponents = () => {
  return <Route exact path="/login" render={() => <div>Login</div>} />
};

const PrivateRouteComponents = () => {
  return <Route exact path="/dashboard" render={() => <div>Dashboard</div>} />
};

function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {/* <Route exact path="/login" render={() => <div>Login</div>} />
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" render={() => <div>Dashboard</div>} /> */}

        <PublicRouteComponents />
        <PrivateRouteComponents />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

edit:

the current solution is to give up the react hook and went straight to JSX.element

```
function App() {
  const PublicRouteComponents = PublicRoutes.map(
    ({restricted, component, path}, key) => <PublicRoute restricted={restricted} component={component} exact path={path} key={key} />
  )

  const PrivateRouteComponents = PrivateRoutes.map(
    ({component, path}, key) => <PrivateRoute component={component} exact path={path} key={key} />
  )

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {PublicRouteComponents}
        {PrivateRouteComponents}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

But, my instructor told me, if you gave an expression instead of class, when the component inside `{PublicRouteComponents}` changes, the app will got re-rendered. Instead if you use `<PublicRouteComponents />`, when the class change, only `<PublicRouteComponents />` will be re-rendered.

I wish to achieve that.

Comment: You need to get rid of the switch.
See: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-bouman-egorx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda I can't give up Switch as nested route is one of the requirements.

Comment: fair enough. What do you mean by nested routes though? Do you mean that only one of the routes should work at a time?

Comment: What about https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-glade-0jxdo ?

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda If you define a `<Route />` inside a component, e.g `<Route path="/news" component={news}/>`, with the intention to render news if user visited `/home/news`, without switch it will not work. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961135/react-router-switch-and-exact-path

Comment: @acbay that would work but by the time you have lots of top-level route e.g `/home`, `/settings`, `/logout`, `/login`, etc, it will decrease the readibility, because you need to use tenary operation to control the top-level route. ps: I am about 4 days into React, so my knowledge is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit, I found the underlying issue in your first code sample.

Basically, React router demands that the route `path` and the `exact` props to be set in the children of the `Router` component.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const LoginRoute = () => {
  return <Route render={() => <div>Login</div>} />;
};

const DashboardRoute = () => {
  return <Route render={() => <div>Dashboard</div>} />;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <DashboardRoute exact path="/dashboard" />
        <LoginRoute exact path="/login" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

If you move the `path` and `exact` props to the `DashboardRoute` and `LoginRoute` components, then react router is unable to match those routes.

See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-engelbart-plc71?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it, from what I observe, if you use `switch`, many did not use `exact` for the route component, with the intention to support nested routes. I removed the `exact` param from the `PublicRouteComponents` and `PrivateRouteComponents` and I can call class `<PublicRouteComponents />` along with `<PrivateRouteComponents />`.